# Generalised solution to find all images on a website, Selenium Python

Tags: python, image, selenium

I am looking to find all images in a website without having to click through every image. For example, the first page contains a bunch of images, click the first image and goes to another page with the story/images. Retrieve the image/text and so on.

Site of interest is: https://www.homestolove.com.au/australian-house-and-garden.

I have found that all image xpaths ends with **/img**, as per below. Is there away to do this using Selenium? Can I use regex to search the pages? Using Selenium because of JS content.

xpath
//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div[3]/article[3]/div/a/span/picture/img

Or do I need to click on every page, kinda painful.

How is this normally done?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, all images are going to be in `<img>` tags, so the xpath must end in `img`, but you can only click on images wrapped with `<a>` tags.  You should be able to have Selenium return all `<img>` tags to you without a complete xpath.  And you can only fetch images for which you know the URL, which means you have to fetch every page.
`curl` and `wget` can mirror and entire web site in one go, including all of the images.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you want to select the images, you can use

```
list_of_img = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
```

and then iterate through list_of_img.
So in your case,

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('webdriver-meta\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.homestolove.com.au/australian-house-and-garden")
imgs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'